# Content-control (web filtering) using machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, filter

I'm trying to build a content-control (web filtering) application using machine learning (just for training purposes). For example define gaming sites.  I'm somewhat familiar with machine learning algorithms, but I have almost no idea how to get features from HTML pages. Can anyone suggest any good material? Maybe some resource with training data? I will be glad of any advice!

Answer (score -1):

You can try [WEKA and histogram analysis](https://wiki.auckland.ac.nz/display/BeSTGRID/WEKA+Tutorials+I) of your data.

Then, you can use a algorithm for getting the most frequent terms.